# Delete an Object referenced only if it isn't referenced elsewhere

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 Mongoose collections (User and Property). A user can have multiple properties and multiple users can have the same property. On deletion of a User, I would like to delete only his references properties that are not referenced by another User.

i.e. Louis has Property 1 and Property 2
John has Property 1 and Property 3
If I delete Louis I would like to delete only Property 2, if I delete John I would like to delete only Property 3.

Actually, I am able to delete all his referenced Properties when I delete a User but I don't know how to manage to delete only the new orphans properties. Do you know anyway to achieve that ?

model/User.js

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first_name: { type: String, default: null },
  last_name: { type: String, default: null },
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: { type: String },
  token: { type: String },
  properties: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'property' }]
});

userSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', function(doc) {
  await Property.deleteMany({_id: { $in: doc.properties }});
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

model/Property.js

```
const propertySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
   },
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['house', 'apartment', 'room' ,'parking', 'pool']
  },
  numberOfBedrooms: { type: Number },
  numberOfBathrooms: { type: Number },
  maxNumberOfGuests: { type: Number }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("property", propertySchema);
```

Thank you a lot for your help!
Louie

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the orphan properties when an user get removed. Here you can see the aggregation:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("60fc97b7431c6e3d7d3e3c79")
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "properties",
      localField: "properties",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "properties"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$properties"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "properties._id",
      foreignField: "properties",
      as: "users"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$users"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "users._id": {
        $ne: ObjectId("60fc97b7431c6e3d7d3e3c79")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$properties._id",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1
    }
  }
])
```

You can see a working example on this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y0Mh6L3M1iE):

After you find the ids of the properties, you can delete them like this:

```
properties.forEach(function(doc) {
  db.properties.deleteOne({ _id: doc._id });
});
```

Feel free to ask me if you have any questions!